# How to send data from iOS to c# web service

Tags: c#, ios, web-services, ipad, rest

I've developed a c# rest web service to comunicate with my iPad app and so far I've been using it with no problem. It's a very simple thing, with a couple of query's and GET method has worked very well for me so far. The problem is now I'm trying to send data from my app to the web service, to insert into my database.

```objective-c
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:mywebsite.com"];
    _theURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:query];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:_theURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:15.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[json UTF8String] length:[json length]];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

This is basically my objective-C code, where I try to establish the connection, set the http method to post and encode the NSData which I want to send. This NSData is just a json string already good to go.

Now in my web service, I try to get this NSData with a Byte[] to decode to string, get my json and on and on. The thing is I'm not being able to do it. My web service method code is:

```c#
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]
public bool submitResults(Byte[] data) {
String jsonString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
try{
  JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var resultado = json.Deserialize<Pergunta[]>(jsonString);
```

... and it goes on. Resuming all this: I can't send the data to the web service so I can insert it in my DB. Any help would be much, much appreciated.

Btw, the error I'm getting is this horrible thing:

> {"Message":"Type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]\u0027 is not supported for deserialization of an array.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertListToObject(IList list, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, IList& convertedList)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

So, trying to help you to help me, here's my json: =)

```
[
  {
    "categoriaID" : 1,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "1",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 1,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "2",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 1,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "3",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 1,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "21",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 2,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "4",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 2,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "5",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 3,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "6",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 3,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "7",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 3,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "8",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 4,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "9",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 4,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "10",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 4,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "11",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 4,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "12",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 4,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "13",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 5,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "14",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 5,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "15",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 5,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "16",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 6,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "17",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 6,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "18",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 6,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "19",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 6,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : "20",
    "nb" : 19574,
    "respostaTipo" : "Bom"
  },
  {
    "categoriaID" : 7,
    "cursoID" : "601",
    "perguntaID" : 22,
    "respostaTexto" : "Adorei!",
    "nb" : 19574
  }
]
```

UPDATE:

After a lot of research, I think it has to do with me serialization in Xcode. It goes like this:

```
_arrayPerguntas = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i = 0; i < _conteudoProgramatico.count; i++) {
        InqueritosResposta *resp = [[InqueritosResposta alloc]init];
        [resp setNb:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_nb]];
        [resp setCursoID:[self indiceSessao:_nomeSessao]];
        [resp setCategoriaID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
        [resp setPerguntaID:[_idConteudoProgramatico objectAtIndex:i]];
        [resp setRespostaTipo:[self codeToString:[_respostasConteudoProgramatico objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [_arrayPerguntas addObject:resp];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < _sessoesPraticas.count; i++) {
        InqueritosResposta *resp = [[InqueritosResposta alloc]init];
        [resp setNb:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_nb]];
        [resp setCursoID:[self indiceSessao:_nomeSessao]];
        [resp setCategoriaID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
        [resp setPerguntaID:[_idSessoesPraticas objectAtIndex:i]];
        [resp setRespostaTipo:[self codeToString:[_respostasSessoesPraticas objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [_arrayPerguntas addObject:resp];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < _materiaisSuporte.count; i++) {
        InqueritosResposta *resp = [[InqueritosResposta alloc]init];
        [resp setNb:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_nb]];
        [resp setCursoID:[self indiceSessao:_nomeSessao]];
        [resp setCategoriaID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]];
        [resp setPerguntaID:[_idMateriaisSuporte objectAtIndex:i]];
        [resp setRespostaTipo:[self codeToString:[_respostasMateriaisSuporte objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [_arrayPerguntas addObject:resp];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < _apresentacao.count; i++) {
        InqueritosResposta *resp = [[InqueritosResposta alloc]init];
        [resp setNb:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_nb]];
        [resp setCursoID:[self indiceSessao:_nomeSessao]];
        [resp setCategoriaID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]];
        [resp setPerguntaID:[_idApresentacao objectAtIndex:i]];
        [resp setRespostaTipo:[self codeToString:[_respostasApresentacao objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [_arrayPerguntas addObject:resp];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < _expectativas.count; i++) {
        InqueritosResposta *resp = [[InqueritosResposta alloc]init];
        [resp setNb:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_nb]];
        [resp setCursoID:[self indiceSessao:_nomeSessao]];
        [resp setCategoriaID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]];
        [resp setPerguntaID:[_idExpectativas objectAtIndex:i]];
        [resp setRespostaTipo:[self codeToString:[_respostasExpectativas objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [_arrayPerguntas addObject:resp];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < _feedBack.count; i++) {
        InqueritosResposta *resp = [[InqueritosResposta alloc]init];
        [resp setNb:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_nb]];
        [resp setCursoID:[self indiceSessao:_nomeSessao]];
        [resp setCategoriaID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:6]];
        [resp setPerguntaID:[_idFeedback objectAtIndex:i]];
        [resp setRespostaTipo:[self codeToString:[_respostasFeedback objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [_arrayPerguntas addObject:resp];
    }
    InqueritosResposta *resp = [[InqueritosResposta alloc]init];
    [resp setNb:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_nb]];
    [resp setCursoID:[self indiceSessao:_nomeSessao]];
    [resp setCategoriaID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7]];
    [resp setPerguntaID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:22]];
    [resp setRespostaTexto:_respostaObservacoes];
    [_arrayPerguntas addObject:resp];

    NSError *writeError = nil;
    NSMutableArray *jsonRespostas = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(InqueritosResposta *resp in _arrayPerguntas)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *jAnswer = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [jAnswer setObject:resp.nb forKey:@"nb"];
        [jAnswer setObject:resp.cursoID forKey:@"cursoID"];
        [jAnswer setObject:resp.categoriaID forKey:@"categoriaID"];
        [jAnswer setObject:resp.perguntaID forKey:@"perguntaID"];
        if (resp.respostaTipo != nil) {
            [jAnswer setObject:resp.respostaTipo forKey:@"respostaTipo"];
        }
        if (resp.respostaTexto != nil) {
            [jAnswer setObject:resp.respostaTexto forKey:@"respostaTexto"];
        }
        [jsonRespostas addObject: jAnswer];
    }
    NSArray *final = [NSArray arrayWithArray:jsonRespostas];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:final options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];

    [self submitData:jsonData];
```

Basically I put all my objects in _arrayPerguntas from different sources. Then I use a dictionary to put them all correctly in another array (final array). The submitData method is the one I entered above with connection setup.
Thanks in advance,

Happy Coding,

ruitex23

Comment: I think it's failing in the de-serialization. Please validate your json object (jsonString). A really good online json validator is http://jsonlint.com

Comment: `\u0027` is the apostrophe.  What does the json from the iPad app look like?

Comment: A web proxy tool like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) is invaluable for debugging this kind of thing. It'll let you see your raw request, any response, etc., so that you can tell whether the problem is on the client side or the server side.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. @Eric, I already did that and everything looks ok.

Comment: @Austin, I don't think I've apostrophes in my json... I posted my json string above, if you wanna take a look.

Comment: Please mark it as correct answer for next users

Comment: What do you want me to mark to? There's no correct answer here yet...

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. Don't use Microsoft's convoluted approach to web services that really only offer a benefit if you're using Microsoft technology to connect to them. Even then it's... shaky at best.

Look into JSONResult MVC Controller Methods. These offer you the most platform independent control over your application's behavior and you won't get any obscure errors like the one you're experiencing. It's pure JSON both ways and there's no guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's failing in the de-serialization. Please validate your json object (jsonString). A really good online json validator is jsonlint.com